# How do I delegate a httpServer response as an express server post response

Tags: node.js, express, httpserver, netweaver

In my scenario, I have frameworks comprising of SAP Business Data(in json format), nodejs middle layer and a Browser front-end. I need to create a real-time application of pull the SAP business to the front-end, make edits and send the edited data back to the sap server.

Now, to achieve this I am using `express` and `http` module. I am using express(post request) to connect to sap backend and retrieve data in json format and have embedded a http webserver, which is hosting the json data as an url used by the front-end.

When the user, make edits in the front-end, I am able to get the response from the httpServer instance response, but the outer express post response is returning before I can delegate the httpResponse form the browser as the express post response.

I am including a part of the code, or illustration :

```
 app.post('/publish', auth, function (request, response) {  
        json = JSON.stringify(request.body);
        //io.sockets.emit("SAP_Event", request.body);     

        http.createServer(function(req,res){
        //var f = 'index.html';

        if(res.url == '/favicon.ico'){ // To handle non-existant favicon request by the http client
            res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
            res.end('Couldn\'t locate the required resource');
            return;
        }

        var headers = { 'Content-type' : 'application/json' ,
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'X-Requested-With,GET,Content-Type'};                              
        res.writeHead(200,headers);
        res.end(json);      
    //***********************************
        if(req.method === "POST") {
        var data = "";

        req.on("data", function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        req.on("end", function() {

            jsonp = qs.parse(data);

        });
    }
    //***********************************               
    }).listen(8080);    

        response.send(jsonp);           

});
```

**Note:** json is the pulled json(sap -> frontend) 
      jsonp is the pushed(modified) json (frontend -> frontend)

I want response.send(jsonp) to send the modified json file, but its returning [] i.e its initial value, moreover I am getting the modified json, the next time restart the server program in sap.
Please Help!!

Comment: Why are you creating http server within a route in express ?? If you want to fetch data from SAP business data you need to get that with `http.request`. But instead you are reading from a file so why do you need an http server ?

Comment: @user568109 Sorry, i put an older code by mistake i.e there is no need to read a file as i am sending json response from SAP data as httpServer response on port 8080.Now...can you please answer !!